# Обработка нажатия на элемент RecyclerView: как это сделать на Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы при нажатии на элемент RecyclerView его текстовое содержимое открывалось в новом фрагменте. Но возникают сложности, в частности как сделать адаптер полем управляющего фрагмента, если он требует передачи в конструктор собственного интерфейса, и как доставать данные из нажатого элемента. И вообще слабо понимаю весь механизм (делаю по примеру кода, который нашла здесь только на java), помогите пожалуйста

```
class NotesFragment : Fragment(), NoteAdapter.ShowDetail {
    private var binding: FragmentNotesBinding? = null
    private var adapter = NoteAdapter()  // вот здесь требуется передать параметр, что сюда писать не знаю.. 

    interface OpenFragment {
        fun addEditFragment() {
        }

    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = NotesFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentNotesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding?.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding!!.rcList.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
        
        binding!!.rcList.adapter = adapter
        binding!!.bAdd.setOnClickListener() {
            (activity as OpenFragment).addEditFragment()
        }
    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        setFragmentResultListener("key") { key, bundle ->
            val result = bundle.getString("bundleKey")
            if (result != null) {
                adapter.addNote(result)
            }

        }
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        binding = null
    }

    override fun onClickElement(message: String) {
       Toast.makeText(context, message, LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Адаптер:

```
class NoteAdapter(_showDetail: ShowDetail) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.NoteHolder>() {

    private val noteList = ArrayList<String>()
    private val showDetail = _showDetail


    interface ShowDetail {
      fun onClickElement(message: String)
    }

    class NoteHolder(item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {
        private val binding = MyNoteItemBinding.bind(item)
        fun bind(note: String) = with(binding) {
            tvMessage.text = note
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_note_item, parent, false)
        return NoteHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(noteList[position])
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            fun onClick() {
                val message = "сообщение"  // здесь пока просто передаю литерал, т.к. не знаю как обратиться к данным из элемента RecyclerView
               showDetail.onClickElement(message)
            }
        });
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return noteList.size
    }

    fun addNote(note: String) {
        noteList.add(note)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> private var adapter = NoteAdapter()  // вот здесь требуется передать
> параметр, что сюда писать не знаю..

Передайте `this`, то есть фрагмент. Так как ваш фрагмент реализует интерфейс `NoteAdapter.ShowDetail`

> val message = "сообщение"  // здесь пока просто передаю литерал, т.к.
> не знаю как обратиться к данным из элемента RecyclerView
> showDetail.onClickElement(message)

```
val message = noteList[holder.adapterPosition]
showDetail.onClickElement(message)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все заработало, NotesFragment получает message. А не подскажите, как правильно уведомить активити, чтобы она открыла новый фрагмент? Ее ведь наверное не стоит подписывать на интерфейс адаптера, т к. им владеет не она, а NotesFragment